# Declaring objects for globals() using a nested for loop

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Firstly, I know I shouldn't be using globals(). I *know* I shouldn't. But I'm using a custom Django API which doesn't allow me to use collections (as far as I can tell), so I'm pretty much stuck with using globals().

I'm trying to design a game where a player will have 1 choice in the first round, 2 choices in the second round, 4 choices in the third round (so the formula for calculating choices per round is num_choices = 2^num_rounds). Of course, the first round has only 1 choice, so I am declaring that statically. However, for subsequent rounds I am trying to use the following code:

```
for i in range(2, NUM_ROUNDS):
    dec_num = math.pow(2, i)
    for j in range(1, int(dec_num)):
         globals()['dec_r{}_{}'.format(i).format(j)] = models.CharField(
             choices=list_of_choices,
             widget=widgets.RadioSelect(),
             blank=False,
             initial='blank'
)
```

However, when I attempt to run my Django app, I receive the following error (and traceback):

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/otree", line 11, in <module>
 sys.exit(otree_cli())
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/otree/management/cli.py", line 113, in otree_cli
 execute_from_command_line(argv)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/otree/management/cli.py", line 133, in    execute_from_command_line
 utility.execute()
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 328, in execute
 django.setup()
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
 apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
 app_config.import_models(all_models)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
 self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
 File "/Users/_____/exp_econ_test/turn_taking_strategic_match_all_players/models.py", line 209, in <module>
 class Player(BasePlayer):
 File "/Users/_____/exp_econ_test/turn_taking_strategic_match_all_players/models.py", line 261, in Player
 initial=Constants.choice1_name
 IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I figure it has something to do with the way that I am declaring the variable name. Is there an alternative I can use? Thanks!

Comment: Which line is causing that error?

Comment: Also, are you trying to create model fields in the global scope? That isn't likely to do anything useful. What is that you're actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: The line causing the error is `initial='blank'` apparently, but when I remove it the error is thrown from blank=False instead. If I declare it using this method using only the round number I don't run into the same issues: http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com.au/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html

Comment: Please post the traceback.

Comment: you need to indent the line starting with `globals()...`

Comment: I see. You're calling `format()` twice. It should just be `.format(i, j)`. But even once you fix that, you're still creating model fields in the global scope--are you doing something with them after that?

Comment: The way that the API that I am using is structured requires me to declare form fields in models. Basically what I am trying to do is to dynamically create a set of form fields so that I do not have to create each of these form fields by hand. The API that I am using is available here: http://otree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html

Comment: Yeah sorry about that Bricky, have fixed the indent.

Comment: Regarding oTree, that's a separate question. I can say though that the approach you're taking seems overly complicated.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any suggestions as to how I might do this without too much spaghetti code?

Comment: You should be aware that using globals will not work as expected when Django is deployed in a production serup with WSGI and multiple threads and processes.

Answer (score 0):

Although your question mentions models, in the comments you talk about form fields. You should not be doing any of this, but add the fields in the form's `__init__` method.

```
self.fields['whatever'] = forms.CharField(...)
```

Comment: Otree does have a participant.vars variable and a session.vars variable, so it may be possible to use that.